# Lemur gets malformed document error when trying to index file

Tags: full-text-indexing

I've been going through a bit of the lemur indexing tutorial here:

http://www.lemurproject.org/tutorials/begin_indexing-1.php

I've created a "corpus" folder, containing one document with the seemingly properly formatted file:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>1</DOCNO>
<TEXT>
    Here is some text
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

and created the following configuration file:

```
<parameters>
  <corpus>
    <path>C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\lemur\corpus</path>
    <class>trectext</class>
  </corpus>
  <memory>256m</memory>
  <index>C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\lemur\index</index>
</parameters>
```

However, when I run:

```
IndriBuildIndex.exe C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\lemur\config\parameter.xml
```

I get the cryptic exception:

```
0:00: Opened repository C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\lemur\index
0:00: Opened C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\lemur\corpus\1
0:00: Error in C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\lemur\corpus\1 : .\src\TaggedDocumentI
terator.cpp(213): Malformed document: C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\lemur\corpus\1
0:00: Closing index
0:00: Finished
```

I looked at the relevant functions in the source, but nothing in particular jumps out at me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving my document file in unix format and it worked. Note however, that for some reason manually fixing the line endings didn't work, so there is something else windows adds to files than lemur doesn't like.

Comment: hi, same issue here but on mac. For unix format you mean UTF8 ?